# Is there an alphabet containing exactly 25 letters?

Tags: alphabets

I am looking for an alphabet containing exactly 25 letters. As we all know, the standard Latin alphabet contains some more letters than 25. As I would like the alphabet to contain exactly 25 letters, it would not suit me to simply remove a handful of letters from the standard Latin alphabet.

Up to this point, I have been attempting to find such an alphabet on my own using the list of writing systems available on Wikipedia, but to no luck. Therefore I am hoping there is a kind soul out there who could provide me with such a thing.

Kind regards,

Comment: What do you want it for, btw?

Comment: A personal project of mine.

Comment: I'm often asked on SE why I want to know a thing. I think this wastes everyone's time, since you could ask this of any question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ogham alphabet](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/ogham.htm) contains 25 letters:

> Number of letters: 25, which are grouped into five aicmí (sing. aicme = group, class). Each aicme is named after its first letter. Originally Ogham consisted of 20 letters or four aicmí; the fifth acime, or Forfeda, was added for use in manuscripts.

Comment: As your answer is highly correct, you will get the accepted answer for this. I would, however, like to see if there are any more alphabets containing 25 letters. Your answer will be accepted, if not earlier, tomorrow.

Comment: I know very little about Ogham, but that website you linked actually shows 26 letters (not counting the start-of-text, space, and end-of-text marks). Is *peith* not considered part of the alphabet?

Answer (score 2):

The [Medieval (Latinised) Futhark](http://omniglot.com/writing/runic.htm#medieval) had 25 letters.

The [Gothic alphabet](http://omniglot.com/writing/gothic.htm) had 27 letters, but two of them had no phonetic value and were never used to write any words, they were used only as numbers. Every Gothic letter had a numeric value, that is why 27 letters were needed — 9 units, 9 tens, and 9 hundreds, 9×3=27. Still, only 25 of them were used to write words of the Gothic language.

Comment: Interesting that they had 27 letters, although only 25 were used. But there still had to be pronunciations for the numerical values without sound, correct?

Comment: @D.Ataro - Yes, like we pronounce digits. These digit-letters were actually copied from the [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Use_as_numerals) which also had digit-letters with no phonetic value, but there were three of them in the Greek alpabet, again to make it 27 letters total, 24 letters with sound + 3 digit-letters. Most of the Gothic letters were also copied from the Greek alphabet.

Comment: @D.Ataro In other words, the two unused letters were more like "3" or "7" in English: symbols used for writing numbers, never words. (Of course, if Gothic had survived to the Internet age, that might have changed...)

Answer (score 2):

The modern Greek alphabet contains only 24 distinct letters. But in lowercase there are 25 glyps: sigma is written ς at the end of a word and σ otherwise.

> α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ ς τ υ φ χ ψ ω

Before the Greek alphabet was standardized for political reasons in the fifth century BC, several regional variants also had 25 letters, including glyphs such as Aeolian digamma (Ϝ, pronounced /w/) or Ionian sampi (ϡ, probably pronounced /ts/).

> Α Β Γ Δ Ε Ζ Η Θ Ι Κ Λ Μ Ν Ξ Ο Π Ρ Σ Τ Υ Φ Χ Ψ Ω Ϝ/ϡ

The English alphabet has had 25 letters at some points in its history. J and V separated from I and U in the mid-1500s, but W was still considered a digraph (like TH) rather than its own letter.

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V X Y Z

Several languages also use a Latin alphabet with fewer than 26 letters. In Classical times* Latin itself had only 23 (lacking J, V, W), and two of those (K, Y) appeared only in foreign words. The 26-letter convention comes from English, since early computer encodings such as 7-bit ASCII were designed only for English usage.

*excluding the reign of Claudius, because nobody liked his new letters